# Windows Phone 8 Custom Contact Store & Extended Properties

Tags: contacts, windows-phone-8

There is no word in documentation about property names that would make users able to launch our custom application from withing people hub - like it works with skype.

Let's say that I want to develop custom IM app for Google Talk, and I would like to store contacts in custom contact store. I would also like to allow users start chat session with particular user directly from people hub.

Skype does this. I don't understand why Microsoft didn't made this API/feature public especially when we have ability to communicate between applications by custom Uris now.

Does anybody know is it achievable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding your own contact to the people hub is allowed through the public API, but adding a slab, like the *Skype (chat, audio, video)* slab in a contact card, is not supported for 3rd party applications.

It's a restricted partner capability.

*(Disclaimer: I work on the Skype for Windows Phone team)*

Comment: It's a shame. Really have no clue why MS makes things so hard & limited. I know that they want to promote their own software (as Skype is now owned by them), but... it would be good for makeing the platform more popular I guess. Anyway - thanks for clearing things out.

Comment: I guess there is. But since there's an app approval process anyway, MS can still control usage of such API to not allow abuse.
Since WP7 I'm waiting for a SIP client, a generic one, something that is available on other platforms. Assuming that now it is possible to create one and allow it to run for all the time - like SKype.

Comment: it would be more convenient for users to go to People and make a SIP call directly from there instead of going first to the app. As far as i know there is not possiblity for an app to integrate with dialer - so user could choose which service he wants to user for voice connection (like on Android). Would be good even for dialing phone numbers by Skype directly from system dialer.

Comment: Sorry if my comment sounded rough but to be honest I'm bit dissapointed by windows phone dev team attitude. I've been asking them about their decisions and they didn't matter to even answer. Seems that only good comments on their product are allowed.

Comment: If you want Android, use Android. Regular application developers aren't even close to understand the complexity of designing a mobile OS. And every platform have their own design decisions.

Comment: Actually I'm using all of them and I'm aware of the complexity that goes behind mobile OS. But in the end it's for users and I'm just saying that such a feature would result in better experience and that it's a pitty that developers can't do that. That's all.
I'm not interested in flame wars, only in discussion that explains why it was done that way not the other. And if I hear "because" or "you would not understand" that upsets me.
I also can understand wp dev team attitude as they probably have a lot of pressure on them as WP has a bumpy way

Comment: As for me it will be really nice to see viber and watsapp integrated to people hub.

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature. Skype is a first party app just like the mail app, text app, and phone app. Yet, Skype is not supported for apps to leverage it. Here's a video of how I'm trying to use apps like Skype: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacVrH9xpYc