# WP8 Contact Store Launch App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, url-scheme, contact-list

I was using Custom Contact Store to save contact on a windows phone 8 App,

already tried that my Url scheme is working, by calling

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("myurlscheme:PageToEditContact?ContactId=0001", UriKind.Absolute));
```

from another App, the target app can be launched to the correct page.

now looking for ways to launch my app from the native contact viewer.
however, when we save the url to a contact ( as follow ); it only open IE and result in "Unsupported address" error message (IE only treat URL as HTTP/HTTPS URL, not check against the custom URL scheme list like iOS Safari).

```
ContactInformation ci = new ContactInformation();
IDictionary<string, object> _knownProperties = await ci.GetPropertiesAsync();
_knownProperties[KnownContactProperties.Url] = "myurlscheme:PageToEditContact?ContactId=0001";
StoredContact _storedContact = new StoredContact(_store,ci);
await _storedContact.SaveAsync();
```

anyone have can give some hint on how to launch an app from WP8 contact list?
(WP7 backward support is not necessary)

Comment: can anyone give some hint?
or confirm it is impossible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik it's not possible yet. We cannot launch app from people hub.

[Windows Phone 8 Custom Contact Store & Extended Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407695/windows-phone-8-custom-contact-store-extended-properties)